# Manipulate Data in the cache proxy server DB

Tags: web-server, proxy, cache

I am wondering if it is possible to manipulate (Insert/Delete) data in the cache proxy server DB... well I'm not sure how a cache proxy server store the data. But What I am interested in is to add resources to the data base of my cache proxy before it gets it.

An example for clarification purpose: say you have downloaded some web page before, and now you are installing a cache proxy server, and you want your server to use the downloaded data, is such a thing possible? discard the fact that it is a stupid way, or web pages can change during time, I would be thankful to know if doing such is even possible. If yes, would you mention what proxy server you think is easier to do so with.

I tried reading Squid source to modify it in a way that such a thing would be possible, but seems to be a lot of work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [link](http://trafficserver.apache.org/docs/trunk/admin/http-proxy-caching/index.en.html#PushingContentintoCache) from Apache Traffic Server is describing what I want to do:

> Traffic Server supports the HTTP PUSH method of content delivery. Using HTTP PUSH, you can deliver content directly into the cache without client requests.

so I guess I would use [Traffic Server](http://trafficserver.apache.org/) instead of Squid. In [their Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traffic_Server) they have their bench marks and it seems to be a powerful tool.

Comment: [Here](http://serverfault.com/questions/471684/push-content-to-apache-traffic-servers-cache/475578#475578) I have described how to actually use Traffic Server to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it should be possible because you have the proxy source code (squid case). You can hack the code and do the necessary changes. Yes, it will require a lot of work. You need to understand how the cached objects are stored and retrieved without corrupting the squid cache.

Comment: true, when you have the source you can _almost_ do anything... but this is not a common feature on web cache systems, is it?