# Push content to Apache Traffic Server's Cache

Tags: cache, perl, apache-traffic-server

I am trying to use [push cache option](http://trafficserver.apache.org/docs/trunk/admin/http-proxy-caching/index.en.html#PushingContentintoCache) of Apache Traffic Server(ATS), to push some content into my cache. I read the documentation, and tried to follow it but I have following questions/problems using this option:

**1 -** In the documentation it mentiones in order to enable PUSH request, modify `proxy.config.http.quick_filter.mask` in `records.config`. Yet I could not find such a super mask to modify in that file. Running `grep -r proxy.config.http.quick_filter.mask .` in ATS configuration folder shows me that this super mask exists in `ip_allow.config` file. Are they the same? Should I modify it there or should I add it to `records.config`? Unfortunately I cannot check this due to my issue No.2.

**2 -** I am not sure how to send this HTTP PUSH request and to whom (on which port - the same port ATS is running on?). There is [perl-script](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=trafficserver.git;a=blob;f=tools/push.pl) which suppose to automate the process, although I was not able to run the script yet(don't know any perl but working on it - getting `Can't locate File/MimeInfo/Magic.pm in @INC`). I wanted to print out the port from the script to see how to push into the cache.

Any hints/tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to finally push content into ATS cache. I used lots of online tutorials as well as ATS support team, Here is how to do so in case anybody else is interested:

Open your records.config in an editor. You can find the file under `/usr/local/etc/trafficserver/` and perform the following modification:

- Make sure ATS cache option is enabled `CONFIG proxy.config.http.cache.http INT 1`
- In order to enable push content into cache first you need to be able to do HTTP PUSH,  set `CONFIG proxy.config.http.push_method_enabled INT 1`
- Have ATS ignore the cahce object age `CONFIG Proxy.config.http.cache.ignore_client_cc_max_age INT 1`
- Other cache configuration should look like following :

  - `CONFIG proxy.config.http.cache.ignore_client_no_cache INT 1`
  - `CONFIG proxy.config.http.cache.ims_on_client_no_cache INT 0`
  - `CONFIG proxy.config.http.cache.ignore_server_no_cache INT 1`
- Set ATS to never validate cache objects `CONFIG Proxy.config.http.cache.when_to_revalidate INT 3`

Then you need to open `ip_allow.config` file in the same folder and do the following modification. `ip_allow.config` is the configuration file which declare IPs and the action each IP is allowed to perform. In order to allow local host to push requests have the following line in the `ip_allow.config` file:

```
src_ip=127.0.0.1                                  action=ip_allow  method=ALL
```

Now your ATS is set to accept push cache. Open a terminal and test by doing the below steps:

```
# telnet 127.0.0.1 8080

Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to 127.0.0.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

(here you paste what you want to push, have in mind it should be VALID http push request!)

```
PUSH http://www.company.com HTTP/1.0
Content-length: 84

HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Content-type: text/html
Content-length: 17

<HTML>
a
</HTML>
```

(the following is what you should get after a successful push into cache)

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Date: Tue, 05 Feb 2013 16:00:22 GMT
Server: ATS/3.2.0
Content-Length: 0

Connection closed by foreign host.
```

And Finally answers to my questions:

1) `proxy.config.http.quick_filter.mask` has been moved from `records.config` to `ip_allow.config`. You can have ATS read the them from different file by changing `CONFIG proxy.config.cache.ip_allow.filename STRING ip_allow.config` in `records.config` file.

2) SinceI managed to work with telnet, I refused using the script.